# Web scraper works locally but not when deployed to Heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, sudo, buildpack

So I'm trying to use the SecretAgent web scraper and it works when I run node app.js but when I deploy my file structure to Heroku, it doesn't work and I get the following massive error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNygo.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwVr4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSKKv.jpg

My call w/ SecretAgent looks like this:

```
const agent = require('secret-agent');

(async () => {
  await agent.goto('https://example.org');
  const title = await agent.document.title;
  const intro = await agent.document.querySelector('p').textContent;
  console.log("intro is " + intro);
  await agent.close();
})();
```

I also tried entering the follow sudo command after cd'ing into the server folder but ended up getting the error 'UnhandledErrorOrRejection', "clientError: 'TypeError: coreTab.goto is not a function'":

```
sudo $(npx puppet-install-deps)
```

This is where I currently am. Any help would be much appreciated. If I can clarify the question better, let me know--thank you for all of your help!

Comment: did you reinstall the browser engine?

Comment: @Gianluca Yes, I also ran the npm install secret-agent/emulate-chrome-88 command in the folder but it said 'Already installed. Skipping download.' (Also with the at sign in front of secret-agent, but I wanted to be able to tag you)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Secret Agent and I certainly haven't deployed a web scraper to Heroku, but it looks like in [the Docs](https://secretagent.dev/docs/advanced/session) Secret Agent tries to store your session data automatically. As far as I understand it, Heroku offers no native storage. Instead, you can hook it up to a database.  I believe what is happening is that your Secret Agent isn't able to store session information, and crashes. Is there a reason you can't run the scraper locally? If you must do it on Heroku, you will need to connect a database (like JawsDB) and use the sessionDir to force it to store your information there.

Comment: Hi, I have a Postgres database connected to my server, could I possibly use that? How would the implementation look?

Comment: You certainly could. According to [this](https://secretagent.dev/docs/overview/configuration#sessions-dir) the easiest way is probably to include the environment variables like that says `Environmental variable: SA_SESSIONS_DIR=/your-absolute-dir-path`. Definitely read through the documentation because we don't really know your use case.